# RichTextbox text into array per 255 char

Tags: arrays, vb.net, split, richtextbox

I want to Split the the text in the RichTextBox per 255 characters into arrays in vb 2010

Example is if the richtextbox have 300 characters:
array[0] = '1 - 255 char
array[1] = '256 - 300 char

Im new in VB and I cant find any decent link or site.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. Personally, I prefer to split strings into a collection *List(Of String)*. It's easier to search and you can easily convert that to an array.

```
'if you want just a collection List(Of String)
Dim resultList As List(Of String) = splitStringIntoList(RichTextBox.text, 255)
'Or if you want just a String array
Dim resultArray As String() = splitStringIntoList(RichTextBox.text, 255).ToArray
Public Function splitStringIntoList(ByVal instring As String, ByVal len As Integer) As List(Of String)
    Dim splitlist As New List(Of String)
    Do While instring.Length > 0
    If instring.Length < len Then
    'remaining string is too short, so shorten len
    len = instring.Length
    End If
    splitlist.Add(instring.Substring(0, len))
    instring = instring.Substring(len)
    Loop
    Return splitlist
End Function
```

Comment: @ Chase Rocker : Double slash ("//") cannot be used for commenting in vb/vb.net

Answer (score 0):

Explanations are commented for reference:

```
  Private Sub days_calc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim s As String = rt.Text ' s holds the string input from the ritch text box
        Dim totl_len = Len(s) ' is the variable to store the length of input string
        Dim count As Integer = totl_len / 255 ' will count the array index(can be set to dynamic
        Dim str_array(10) As String ' required to save the output array
        Dim n As Integer = 254 ' limits the no. of characters per index is 255
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
            If n < totl_len Then
                n = 254
            Else
                n = totl_len
            End If
            str_array(i) = s.Substring(j, n).ToString 'Assign the values to the array
            j = n
            n = n + 254
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1  'display the content of the array
            MsgBox(str_array(i).ToString())
        Next
    End Sub
```